# Call method from controller via Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is how I call it now:

```
if (firstPass == secondPass) {
    $.ajax({
                url: "/Settings/EditSettings",
                type: "PUT",
                data: {
                    user: "someName",
                    pass: "password",
                    email: "someEmail"
                }
            });  
}
```

My controller is called SettingsController, and the method in it:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Put)]
    public void EditSettings(string user, string pass, string email)
    {
        ///
    }
```

But it never gets called. Why?

Comment: i have copied your provided code and executed it... the call is working like a charm...
Can you check if your if (firstPass == secondPass) condition is getting successful?

Comment: @UsmanMasood Yes it is, if I put alert before the ajax code, the alert gets executed.

Comment: @UsmanMasood But I get error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @Scree please tell me had you included Jquery before calling this? :)

Comment: @UsmanMasood That was the problem :) Pls answer so that I can choose your answer as best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code seems fine.. the only issue appears to be not inclusion of Jquery before calling this Javascript snippet.

(for details see the comments)